# Android - TabLayout coming up empty on samsung galaxy tab 10.1

Tags: android, layout, galaxy-tab, samsung-mobile

I am using a tablayout nested inside a dialog that I use for a menu in my app. It works fine on all other devices except the galaxy tab 10.1 on which it just comes up empty. Theres not one single error, warning, or mention of such in the logcat or anywhere and I dont see anything coming up null when trying to debug. Anyone have any ideas on what could be the problem with this specific device and a tablayout nested in a dialog? Should I just move the whole tablayout menu into its own activity/subactivity?

**Heres what I am doing with the code.....its nothing to crazy:**

```
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.maintabmenu);
final TabHost tabs = (TabHost) dialog.findViewById(R.id.my_tabhost);
tabs.setup();
tabs.setCurrentTab(0);
TabSpec tspec11 = tabs.newTabSpec("New Tab");
    tspec11.setIndicator("User");

tspec11.setContent(R.id.ScrollView01);
tabs.addTab(tspec11);

TabSpec tspec2 = tabs.newTabSpec("New Tab");
tspec2.setIndicator("Settings");

tspec2.setContent(R.id.ScrollView02);
tabs.addTab(tspec2);

TabSpec tspec3 = tabs.newTabSpec("New Tab");
tspec3.setIndicator("My options");
tspec3.setContent(R.id.ScrollView03);
tabs.addTab(tspec3);
```

**and heres the xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/my_tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
   <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">

           <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

              <RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bggreydotted"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/usersname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="User Info" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/profileimage2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/favicon_yellow_g_metal_bg2" />


<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/drawMark"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/createMarks"
    android:background="@null"

    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttondrawmark" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/zmLevel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_below="@+id/search"
    android:background="@null"

    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonzoomlevel" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/license"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/mypreferences"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonlicense" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/zmLevel"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@null" 
    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonmapview" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/mypreferences"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/drawMark"
    android:background="@null"

    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonuserpreference" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/marksNearMe"
    android:background="@null"

    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonmarksearch" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/createMarks"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonuploadphoto" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/marksNearMe"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonmarksnearme" />

</RelativeLayout>

            </ScrollView>

            <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView02"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

               <TextView 
                   android:id="@+id/TextView02"
                   android:text="wizard"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                   android:paddingLeft="15dip"
                   android:paddingTop="15dip"
                   android:paddingRight="20dip"
                   android:paddingBottom="15dip"/>

            </ScrollView>

            <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView03"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

               <RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="300dip"
android:background="@drawable/bggreydotted"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/userinfo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="USER INFO" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/profileimage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/favicon_yellow_g_metal_bg2" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/sky"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/mymarks"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonsky" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/myclicks"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonmyclicks" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/mygallery"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/myclicks"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonmygallery" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/mymarks"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mygallery"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonmymarks" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/help"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/createuser"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonhelp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/createuser"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/logout"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttoncreateuser" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonlogin3" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/logout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/login"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonlogout" />

</RelativeLayout>

            </ScrollView>

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Comment: Is the `Dialog` the size you would expect it to be? What version of the OS is the tablet running?

Comment: yes the dialog is about the size I expected it to be. The tabs are also on the top and I can switch tabs but the content from my layout is not showing up. Also the device is running 3.2

Comment: Do you think it could be fixed by using a layoutinflator

Comment: Dialogs have been deprecated and replaced with DialogFragment. I don't see enough of your code to be able to say which one you are using. But I think if you are using the old Dialogs then definitely try changing those to Dialog fragment.

Comment: Will those be backwards compatible back to 2.2? Ill try implementing them for now being that I want it to work on a tablet but Im trying to keep my app working back to 2.2.

Comment: Yes, Google provides a `android-compatibility-v4.jar` which provides the classes needed for older versions. I use it on my project which supports 2.2+

Comment: Oh cool thats awesome :) I havent thought to use that even though Ive come across its mention on other sites. Ill definitely give it a shot and post back when I get it working on my tablet.

Comment: So Ive moved my tablayout into a fragment dialog but that doesnt seem to do anything for the problem I seem to have. It still works perfectly fine on other devices but for some reason no content shows up in my tabs its just all blank.....very strange. I may just make my menu its own simple activity to see if that works any better.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a Galaxy Tab 10 but I do use a lot of Dialogs in my app, you have me wondering about my own app on that device now. Did you find a particularly useful link on how to to use DialogFragments?

Comment: There was actually quite a few online tutorials but most of them just extend the sample that comes strait from googles own site. I do find it strange because I tested on two motorola phones (a bionic and droid x2) and also on a htc dream or tmobile g1 a samsung infuse that runs 2.3 and tmobile mytouch 4g and all those devices run the tablayout just fine. I think it has something to do possibly with the tablet or 3.2 but Im not sure

Comment: Also I tested other layouts inside the dialog and they work just fine. It has something to do with a tabHost.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have figured it out :)

For my case I had to make my xml layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/my_tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">



              <RelativeLayout 
                  android:id="@+id/rlone"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bggreydotted"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/usersname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="User Info" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/profileimage2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/favicon_yellow_g_metal_bg2" />


<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/drawMark"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/createMarks"
    android:background="@null"

    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttondrawmark" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/zmLevel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_below="@+id/search"
    android:background="@null"

    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonzoomlevel" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/license"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/mypreferences"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonlicense" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/zmLevel"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@null" 
    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonmapview" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/mypreferences"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/drawMark"
    android:background="@null"

    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonuserpreference" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/marksNearMe"
    android:background="@null"

    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonmarksearch" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/createMarks"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonuploadphoto" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/marksNearMe"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonmarksnearme" />

</RelativeLayout>


               <RelativeLayout 
                   android:id="@+id/rltwo"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bggreydotted"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/userinfo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="USER INFO" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/profileimage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/favicon_yellow_g_metal_bg2" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/sky"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/mymarks"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonsky" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/myclicks"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonmyclicks" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/mygallery"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/myclicks"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonmygallery" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/mymarks"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mygallery"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonmymarks" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/help"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/createuser"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonhelp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/createuser"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/logout"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttoncreateuser" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonlogin3" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/logout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/login"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/graffitbuttonlogout" />

</RelativeLayout>



    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The difference in layout code is that  removed the padding and changed the TabWidget layoutHeight to wrap_content. I think thats why it was comming up blank.